# ¿ Cómo reemplazar letras con tildes por las mismas sin tildes? "á" por "a"

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando que me acepte los tildes pero nadie ha conseguido solucionarme dicho problema, no me lee directamente las letras con tildespor tanto la única solución que creo que es más sencillo es que si introduces un tilde, te lo cambie por la misma sin tilde, es decir, "á" por "a" , "é" por "e" ... y así.

**Os voy a ayudar también pues he encontrado este código que hace lo que os comento, pero no sé como meterlo en mi código.**

*Ejemplo de cambio de caracteres:*

```
public static String remove1(String input) {
  // Cadena de caracteres original a sustituir.
  String original = "áàäéèëíìïóòöúùuñÁÀÄÉÈËÍÌÏÓÒÖÚÙÜÑçÇ";
  // Cadena de caracteres ASCII que reemplazarán los originales.
  String ascii = "aaaeeeiiiooouuunAAAEEEIIIOOOUUUNcC";
  String output = input;
  for (int i=0; i<original.length(); i++) {
      // Reemplazamos los caracteres especiales.
      output = output.replace(original.charAt(i), ascii.charAt(i));
  }//for i
  return output;
}
```

Eso es lo que he encontrado por Internet , uno de tantos, pero **mi código es este**, (y sí que funciona):

```
public class Admin extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText titulo_in;
EditText descripcion_in;
Button btnActualizarA;


String recuperado="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.admin);

    titulo_in = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.titulo_in);
    descripcion_in = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.descripcion_in);

   // titu = titulo_in.getText().toString();
    //desc = descripcion_in.getText().toString();



    final Bundle recupera=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(recupera!=null){
        recuperado=recupera.getString("cod");
    }

    btnActualizarA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.publicar);
    btnActualizarA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Thread tr2=new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ActualizarPost(recuperado, titulo_in.getText().toString(), descripcion_in.getText().toString());

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se ha completado la publicación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            tr2.start();
        }
    });


}

public void ActualizarPost(String c, String tit, String des){
   // HttpURLConnection conection=null;
    try{
        String titleUtf8 = URLEncoder.encode(tit, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+","%20");
        String descriptionUtf8 = URLEncoder.encode(des, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+","%20");

        String urlParameters="cod="+c+"&tit="+titleUtf8+"&des="+descriptionUtf8;


        URL url=new URL("http://rudeboys.esy.es/ramiroconnect/publicar.php");
        HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       // conection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","UTF-8");

        //estableciendo el metodo
        conection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        //longitud de datos que se envian
        conection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
       // conection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");


        //comando para la salida de datos
        conection.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conection.getOutputStream());
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(wr, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(urlParameters);
        writer.close();

        InputStream is =conection.getInputStream();
    }catch (Exception ex){}
}
```

}

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el código para que me actualice los datos en la BD sin tildes?

Comment: ¿Qué valor es el que quieres poner sin tildes?

Comment: como? Simplemente quiero que cuando pongas cualquier letra con tilde le salga la misma sin tilde. Ejemplo: El usuario escribirá : "El camión es marrón" y en la base de datos saldrá: "El camion es marron"

Comment: Y de todas las variables cadena que puedes tener en tu código ¿cuál es la que quieres cambiar?

Comment: titulo y descripción. "titleUtf8" y "descriptionUtf8". Están en el método void ``ActualizarPost`` . El usuario tiene un titulo y descripción, en ambos se quiere cambiar, para que pueda leer los acentos en ambos campos.

Comment: El código del método `remove1` que has pegado también te va a cambiar las `ñ/Ñ` por `n/N` y las `ç/Ç` por `c/C` no sé si eso también es lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues para usar lo que pones de ejemplo tienes que usar:

```
ActualizarPost(recuperado,
    remove1(titulo_in.getText().toString()),
    remove1(descripcion_in.getText().toString()));
```

Así estarás actualizando el valor sin tildes.

Comment: He puesto el método remove1 arriva del de actualizar post, donde coloco lo que has puesto?

Comment: Donde estás actualizando en tu método `run` (sustituyes la línea donde usas `ActualizarPost`) y el código del método `remove1` simplemente lo añades como otro método más de tu clase.

Comment: De acuerdo, voy a probar

Comment: funciona, perfecto, gracias.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes crear una función que cambié los tildes, como la siguiente:

```
static String removerTildes(String cadena) {
    return cadena.replace("Á", "A")
            .replace("É", "E")
            .replace("Í", "I")
            .replace("Ó", "O") ­
            .replace("Ú", "U")
            .replace("á", "a")
            .replace("é", "e")
            .replace("í", "i")
            .replace("ó", "o")
            .replace("ú", "u");
}
```

Ejemplo

```
String palabraConTildes = "óooóólíiiií téeníi pololí";
palabraSinTildes = removerTildes(palabraConTildes);
Log.d(TAG, "palabraSinTildes: "+palabraSinTildes);
```

Y el log dirá: "oooooliiiii teenii pololi"

Comment: te doy +1 , pero la respuesta me la respondió antes él

Comment: gracias de todas formas

Comment: Supongo que emplearé este solcución ( la de quitar los acentos y sustituir), porque lo de que acepte los acentos es realmente difícil.

Comment: @RfMvs puedes cambiar la respuesta correcta en ese caso

Comment: No no , me refiero, la de él me sirve, no me he expresado bien, digo que emplearé vuestra solución en vez de hacer lo que realmente quería , pues es una solución. Respecto a destacada, pongo la suya pues me lo dijo antes pero me sirven **Ambas** te he puesto un +1 tambien

Comment: Pregunta sencilla, respuesta sencilla. Gracias